# binding more elements in one row of a grid

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, rows

I want to have 5 Columns and bind a list of Elements. Each Element has a Picture. I want to display the Picture of 5 Elements in one Row.

Actually this is my code

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Buildings}" Width="350" Margin="0,5,0,10">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" CanHorizontallyScroll="True">
                <!--<TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Name}" />-->
                <Image Source="{Binding Name,Converter={StaticResource CivToImage}}" Height="50px" Width="50px"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I also want to give informations like Name (Buildings.Name) and Costs(Buildings.Costs) with a Tooltip.

Unfortunally i can only display one Element in a Row ...
I tried a solution with a grid, but it just showed one image per Row:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Buildings}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Name,Converter={StaticResource CivToImage}}" Height="50px" Width="50px"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why did it not work, what did it do/say?

Comment: it displayed only one column ...

Comment: The only reason I can see that it failed is because you binding at individual Building levele didn't work.

Comment: sry when i said, it didnt work, i meant that it was not in that what i wanted, I want to show 5 Columns with Data, but it shows me one Image per Column

Answer (score 0):

When you use grid like:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Name ="Image1" Source="{Binding Name,Converter={StaticResource CivToImage}}"  Height="50px" Width="50px"/>
    <Image Name ="Image2" Source="{Binding Name,Converter={StaticResource CivToImage}}" Height="50px" Width="50px"/>
</Grid>
```

All items will be positioned at 0,0 so you will see only one that will be on top. You could position these images like first is 0,0 second is in this case 50px,0.

But I think the best way would be to add:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Name ="Image1" Source="{Binding Name,Converter={StaticResource CivToImage}}" Height="50px" Width="50px"/>
    <Image Name ="Image2" Source="{Binding Name,Converter={StaticResource CivToImage}}" Height="50px" Width="50px"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

This will position all your items next to each other. Hope this was the case as I'm not 100% sure I understood the problem.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this doesn't work, i get 2 items, but they are the same item ... I want to get the next item in the same row

Comment: OK, so could you explain how does your Buildings class look like and what exactly does CivToImage converter do?